# How to Develop Web Compiler for c, c++, java

Tags: php, compiler-construction, evaluation, online-compilation

Can anyone tell me how I should approach the development of a web-based interface for remote compiling, based a compiler like InterviewStreet or Codeacademy for c, c++ ?

I want to develop the using PHP (Language doesn't matter anyway)

Is there any Opensource API for this kind of task?

Thanks

Comment: You can't be serious right? A compiler for C++ written in PHP??? You might as well ride a dead horse.

Comment: "please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved" Well I considered it.

Comment: He obviously means a web interface to do remote compiling: you post your c++ code, the Server compiles and runs it and outputs the result on the web page. This is very common

Comment: @TonyTheLion It would be nice to have a c++ compiler in javascript.

Comment: @TonyTheLion Please check website i mentioned for your reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `shell_exec()` and `gcc`.

I.e. basically compile from command-line with the usual compilers (g++, javac among others).

Always be careful of the security though, restrict the rights of the user compiling and running the compiled programs.

Comment: Please add a comment when downvoting.
This could be done, but should be done carefully taking care of security

Comment: @Bgi Thanks Can you explain in brief what would be the architecture if want to make site like TopCoder, CodeAcademy or Interview Street ?

Comment: I can't really tell you, I'm no expert about that. But when doing that you must keep in mind everything a hacker could try to make your server crash or to hack it.